# number of flutter local notification schedule and a list of notification IDs

Tags: flutter, localnotification

Is there a way to get a list of how many reservation notifications have been registered?

I want to know the number of flutter local notification schedule and a list of notification IDs.

Comment: You should post code snippet with your solution attempt, that way people can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Add this function inside your local notification class and you can call it from outside with an object

```
returnPendingNotifications() async {
    final List<PendingNotificationRequest> pendingNotificationRequests =
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests();
    return pendingNotificationRequests;
  }
```

It'll return a list of pending notifications with id, title, body and payload

Comment: Is there any way to know the schedule time?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The workaround I found was storing the time in the payload instead